# HTTP Webrequest Wrapper / Helper Library

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I was wondering if you guyz could let me know of good http wrapper / helper library to get and send data for use with .NET Framework 3.5+

Webclient is not fit for my needs, so looking for a good alternative. If i don't find any good, then i will use custom webrequest code only.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with WebClient that it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Many things like Uploading File, we can't specify the form name of file, not really easy to send multipart request etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some libraries for use in REST clients or with HTTP:

1. WebClient, HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse as you have said
2. HttpClient class

   For .NET 4.5 but a really cool thing
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx
3. RestSharp

   Samples and docu and even source code try to find on off. site
   http://restsharp.org/,

When you need some alternative to .NET built-in classes like WebClient and HttpClient - I suggest to try RestSharp

Answer (score 1):

I've also had good luck recently with Service Stack (.NET 3.5 and 4) http://www.servicestack.net/.

Comment: ServiceStack is REST server library, and @Walter-Boss needs client

Comment: ServiceStack provides a range of clients: [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client), and for a number of different endpoints (REST, SOAP etc.)

Comment: Are these clients independent from service stack? Do they need a special DTOs? Could I consume arbitrary web services not written with servicestack with them or make HTTP request to arbitrary web pages? Thanks

Comment: You can certainly use them to consume web services written in other frameworks. The DTO is quite flexible (POCO), but you would of course need to know what the server was expecting in terms of request/response.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I haven't known that servicestack also has client libraries.